# C free() invalid next size (normal)

Tags: c, free

I'm fairly new to C and I can't seem to figure out what seems to be a pretty simple pointer problem.  My program adds line numbers to a file.  It reads in the file line by line and then adds a line number to the beginning of each line. It works fine on each file individually as you can see below:

```
soccer@soccer-Dell-DV051:~/code C$ ./a.out test.c
soccer@soccer-Dell-DV051:~/code C$ ./a.out miscellaneousHeader.h
soccer@soccer-Dell-DV051:~/code C$ ./a.out test.c miscellaneousHeader.h
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid next size (normal): 0x08648170 ***
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
soccer@soccer-Dell-DV051:~/code C$
```

but when I run them together I get the above error.  The following code is my program.

Compiler.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "lineNumAdderHeader.h"
#include "miscellaneousHeader.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    if (argc < 2)
        fatal("in main(). Invalid number of arguments");

    int i = 1;
    while (i < argc){
        lineNumAdder(argv[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I have narrowed the problem to the `lineNumPtr`. The error occurs when `lineNumPtr` is freed after the second file. If `lineNumPtr` is not freed, which I know is bad programming, the program works just fine.

lineNumAdder.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "miscellaneousHeader.h"
#include "lineNumAdderHeader.h"

int lineSizeChecker(FILE*, int);
int lineNumChecker(char*);
int fileSizeChecker(FILE*);


void lineNumAdder(char* filename){
    int lineSpace, position, lineNumCheckerBoolean, numOfDigits, fileSpace;
    int lineNum = 1;
    char *lineNumPtr = NULL;
    char *numberedFile = NULL;
    char *nonNumberedLine = NULL;
    char *originalLine = NULL;
    FILE *file = errorCheckedFopen(filename, "r+w");

    while(1){
        position = ftell(file);

        if (position == 0){
            fileSpace = fileSizeChecker(file);
            numberedFile = errorCheckedMalloc(fileSpace);
        }

        lineSpace = lineSizeChecker(file, position);
        if (position == 0)
            originalLine = errorCheckedMalloc(lineSpace);
        else
            originalLine = realloc(originalLine, lineSpace);

        if (fgets(originalLine, lineSpace, file) == NULL)
            break;

        lineNumCheckerBoolean = lineNumChecker(originalLine);

        if (lineNumCheckerBoolean == 0){
            if (position == 0)
                nonNumberedLine = errorCheckedMalloc(lineSpace - 9);
            else
                nonNumberedLine = realloc(nonNumberedLine, lineSpace - 9);

            strcpy(nonNumberedLine, &originalLine[9]);
        }
        else{
            if (position == 0)
                nonNumberedLine = errorCheckedMalloc(lineSpace);
            else
                nonNumberedLine = realloc(nonNumberedLine, lineSpace);

            strcpy(nonNumberedLine, originalLine);

            fileSpace += 8;
            numberedFile = realloc(numberedFile, fileSpace);
        }

        numOfDigits = intDigitFinder(lineNum);
        if (position == 0)
            lineNumPtr = errorCheckedMalloc(numOfDigits);
        else
            lineNumPtr = realloc(lineNumPtr, numOfDigits);
        sprintf(lineNumPtr, "%d", lineNum);

        strcat(numberedFile, "/*");
        strcat(numberedFile, lineNumPtr);
        strcat(numberedFile, "*/");
        if (lineNum < 10)
            strcat(numberedFile, "    ");
        else if (lineNum >= 10 && lineNum < 100)
            strcat(numberedFile, "   ");
        else if (lineNum >= 100 && lineNum < 1000)
            strcat(numberedFile, "  ");
        else if (lineNum >= 1000 && lineNum < 10000)
            strcat(numberedFile, " ");
        strcat(numberedFile, nonNumberedLine);
        lineNum++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(originalLine);
    free(nonNumberedLine);
    free(lineNumPtr);
    free(numberedFile);
}

int lineNumChecker(char *comment){
    if (sizeOf(comment) < 8)
        return 1;

    if (comment[7] == '/' || comment[6] == '/' || comment[5] == '/' || comment[4] == '/')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
}

int lineSizeChecker(FILE *file, int position){
    int i = 2;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        i++;

    fseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);

    return i;
}

int fileSizeChecker(FILE *file){
    int i = 2;

    while (fgetc(file) != EOF)
        i++;

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return i;
}
```

miscellaneous.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "miscellaneousHeader.h"

void fatal(char*);

int sizeOf(char *data){
    int i = 1;

    while(data[i-1] != '\n')
        i++;

    return i;
}

void *errorCheckedMalloc(size_t size){
    void *ptr = malloc(size);

    if (ptr == NULL)
        fatal("in errorCheckedMalloc(). Memory Allocation Failure\n");
    else
        return ptr;
}

FILE *errorCheckedFopen(char *filename, char *mode){
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, mode);

    if (file == NULL)
        fatal("in errorCheckedFopen(). File Opening Failure\n");
    else
        return file;
}

void fatal(char *errorMessage){
    char* completedErrorMessage = errorCheckedMalloc(sizeOf(errorMessage)+17);

    strcpy(completedErrorMessage, "[!!] Fatal Error ");
    strcat(completedErrorMessage, errorMessage);

    perror(completedErrorMessage);

    free(completedErrorMessage);

    exit(-1);
}

int intDigitFinder(int num){
    int digits = 0;

    do {
        num /= 10;
        digits++;
    } while (num != 0);

    return digits;
}

void *reMalloc(void *ptr, size_t size){
    char buf[strlen(ptr) + 1];
    strcpy(buf, ptr);

    free(ptr);

    ptr = errorCheckedMalloc(size);

    if(size >= strlen(buf))
        strcpy(ptr, buf);

    return ptr;
}
```

I apologize for the length. This is my first post and I wanted to make sure that I provided enough information for you guys to give me the best answers possible. Thank you for any and all answers.  They are much appriciated.

Comment: Use the debugger. Narrow your problem search.

Comment: And *never* line-number your code posts. it makes them quite-impossible to cut-paste for functional-testing. If there is something in the code you need to call attention to put a big-op-comment saying LOOK HERE or some-such. If there is a line number in a error message, mark *that line* with a comment; but *please* don't number entire listings.

Comment: Suggest `char *nonNumberedLine = NULL;`

Comment: If your textbook told you that `void main` is correct, it may have fed you other misinformation as well; its author does not know the C language very well. `main` returns `int`. See the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com), questions 11.12a through 11.15.

Comment: Can you revisit line number 54 of `lineNumAdder.c`? I tried gdb and found out that you are incrementing `fileSpace` by 8 whereas size of `numberedFile` is incremented by a much larger size(size of each line of the input file). Is the logic expected? I could see the error mentioned in question at that line however I dont know if that is the root cause because realloc should not fail if the size is less than the ptr.

Comment: at reMalloc : should be `char buf[strlen(ptr)+1];`, but unused this.

Comment: my apologies for the line numbers they were already part of the file when I copied it I will make sure to remove them next time.  Thank you for the information about the main function as well. I increase 'fileSpace' by 8 because 8 characters is how much space each line number takes up. I then use 'realloc' to increase the array size to now hold the line number and the line that was read in. @sarok

Comment: So if you are holding the line number + the line that was read in, shouldn't your array increase by 8+strlen(line that was read in)?

Comment: No because I get the size of the file before I originally malloc the array. Then it only needs to increase by 8 if the line read in does not have a line number. Otherwise there is already space in the array for the line number because it was counted in the size of the file. @sarok

Comment: @user3273091 ok. But when I ran through gdb, I could actually see the size of string `numberedFile` getting greater that `fileSpace` which as per your description seems a bug to me.

Comment: I did not notice that before. I'm not sure what exactly I should increment it by however. I get the file size when I originally malloc `numberedFile` so shouldn't everything but the 8 bytes that form the line number be accounted for?  I have it add 8 to `numberedFile` if there wasn't a line number already on it. If there was already a line number on the line its 8 bytes should have been counted when I retrieved the file size which means it would have already been malloced. @sarok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, so I have gotten it to work.  I have tweaked the `lineNumAdder.c` file.  The program now increases `numberedFile`'s size by the line each time it is read in. Also the error was occuring on the second file because when I would `strcat` the line number into the malloced area junk was already stored there, so `numberedFile` would overflow. I have fixed this by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`. Thank you to all who gave answers and commented. They all helped tremendously.

Here is the completed lineNumAdder.c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "miscellaneousHeader.h"
#include "lineNumAdderHeader.h"

int lineSizeChecker(FILE*, int);
int lineNumChecker(char*);
int fileSizeChecker(FILE*);


void lineNumAdder(char* filename){
    int lineSpace, filePosition, lineNumCheckerBoolean, numOfDigits;
    int fileSpace = 0;
    int lineNum = 1;
    char *lineNumPtr = NULL;
    char *numberedFile = NULL;
    char *nonNumberedLine = NULL;
    char *originalLine = NULL;
    FILE *file = errorCheckedFopen(filename, "r+w");

    while(1){
        filePosition = ftell(file);

        lineSpace = lineSizeChecker(file, filePosition);
        if (filePosition == 0)
            originalLine = calloc(1, lineSpace);
        else
            originalLine = realloc(originalLine, lineSpace);

        if (fgets(originalLine, lineSpace, file) == NULL)
            break;

        lineNumCheckerBoolean = lineNumChecker(originalLine);
        if (lineNumCheckerBoolean == 0){
            fileSpace += lineSpace;
            if (filePosition == 0){
                nonNumberedLine = calloc(1, lineSpace - 8);

                numberedFile = calloc(1, fileSpace);
            }
            else{
                nonNumberedLine = realloc(nonNumberedLine, lineSpace - 8);

                numberedFile = realloc(numberedFile, fileSpace);
            }

            strcpy(nonNumberedLine, &originalLine[9]);
        }
        else{
            fileSpace += lineSpace + 9;
            if (filePosition == 0){
                nonNumberedLine = calloc(1, lineSpace);

                numberedFile = calloc(1, fileSpace);
            }
            else{
                nonNumberedLine = realloc(nonNumberedLine, lineSpace);

                numberedFile = realloc(numberedFile, fileSpace);
            }

            strcpy(nonNumberedLine, originalLine);
        }

        numOfDigits = intDigitFinder(lineNum);
        if(filePosition == 0)
            lineNumPtr = calloc(1, numOfDigits);
        else
            lineNumPtr = realloc(lineNumPtr, numOfDigits);
        sprintf(lineNumPtr, "%d", lineNum);

        strcat(numberedFile, "/*");
        strcat(numberedFile, lineNumPtr);
        strcat(numberedFile, "*/");
        if (lineNum < 10)
            strcat(numberedFile, "    ");
        else if (lineNum >= 10 && lineNum < 100)
            strcat(numberedFile, "   ");
        else if (lineNum >= 100 && lineNum < 1000)
            strcat(numberedFile, "  ");
        else if (lineNum >= 1000 && lineNum < 10000)
            strcat(numberedFile, " ");
        strcat(numberedFile, nonNumberedLine);
        lineNum++;
    }

    fclose(file);
    free(originalLine);
    free(nonNumberedLine);
    free(lineNumPtr);
    free(numberedFile);
}

int lineNumChecker(char *comment){
    if (sizeOf(comment) < 8)
        return 1;

    if (comment[7] == '/' || comment[6] == '/' || comment[5] == '/' || comment[4] == '/')
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;
 }

 int lineSizeChecker(FILE *file, int position){
    int i = 2;
    int ch;

    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        i++;

    fseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);

    return i;
}

int fileSizeChecker(FILE *file){
    int i = 2;

    while (fgetc(file) != EOF)
        i++;

fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);

    return i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it's difficult to debug this... But at the very least:

```
int sizeOf(char *data) {
    int i = 1;

    while(data[i-1] != '\n' && data[i-1] != '\0')
        i++;

    return i;
}
```